# Ionic 5 vertical slide

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic5

I take ionic 5, I would like to have a vertical slide from the bottom to the top in my application. I tried to implement it but it doesn't work.

```
<ion-slides pager direction="vertical">
  <ion-slide>

  </ion-slide>
 </ion-slides>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`direction` is not a property of the `ion-slides` element,  it is a configuration option of [swiper](https://swiperjs.com/demos/#vertical_slider).

To use it in Ionic, you set the `direction` property on the `ion-slides` options to 'vertical':

```
slideOpts = {
    direction: 'vertical',
    initialSlide: 0,
    speed: 400,
};
```

Your HTML template should already contain something like:

```
<ion-slides pager="true" [options]="slideOpts">
    <ion-slide>
        <h1>Slide 1</h1>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
        <h1>Slide 2</h1>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
        <h1>Slide 3</h1>
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't get the navigation buttons off.

Comment: Just set pager to false in the template.